# Navbar collapse work on browser, not on smartphone

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap

When I resize my browser window and make it smaller, the navbar nicely creates a collapse menu with a button on the right top corner. When I view the same site on my android phone, the navbar menu is always collapsed and the top right corner button is not visible. How can this be solved? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Groundhops</title>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">

        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="#">My Groundhops</a>

        <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li>Clubs</li>
              <li>Visits</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12">Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to be a twitter bootstrap issue on opera mobile, it works on the default android browser. So my code seems OK.

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3621

Answer (score 5):

You're probably missing the meta tag required for mobile devices to properly scale.

So stick this in the `head` section of your page and try again:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: @John Can you post your markup or a link to your site? If the responsive feature is working fine in your desktop and not on your mobile device than it must be something specific to your setup, your markup might tell us something as well.

Comment: Markup added in original post

Comment: @John just noticed your reply, are you also including the [bootstrap-responsive](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css) sheet on your application?

Comment: I have a "bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss" file and in that there is a line "@import "bootstrap-responsive";" so that should load the bootstrap-responsive sheet.